# how to put password inphp code to sqlite?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite using an example I found here, but I can't get it to work.  I want include to require a database password to decode it.

I got error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'

With message `SQLite3::open() expects parameter 2 to be long`...etc

```
<?php
  class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
       $this->open('mySQLiteDB.sqlite','','password');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();

   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
$sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Nom='CAF';
EOF;

   $ret = $db->query($sql);
   while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
      echo "Nom = ". $row['Nom'] . "\n";
   }
   echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   $db->close();            
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite clear. The second parameter (flags) for the `open()`-method must be an integer. You're currently passing an empty string.

Change:

```
$this->open('mySQLiteDB.sqlite','','password');
```

to use the default flags:

```
$this->open('mySQLiteDB.sqlite', SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE, 'password');
```

You can read more in [**the documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php).

Comment: Hi thx for you help. But dont work too...  i got this message now : Warning: SQLite3::query() [sqlite3.query]: Unable to prepare statement: 26, file is encrypted or is not a database in /home/...

Comment: @Frenchy90 - That's a separate issue. Are sure it's actually a sqlite3 db and not an earlier version? The sqlite3 driver isnt backwards compatible. However, if this answer solved your initial issue (the error message you got), then you should accept it.

Comment: ill try it to test compatibility to server :                                                  <?php
/*$dbname='base';
if(!class_exists('SQLite3'))
  die("SQLite 3 NOT supported.");

$base=new SQLite3($dbname, 0666);
echo "."; */
?>                                                                                                            And i got message : SQLite 3 supported, Normaly thats good ? no

Comment: @Frenchy90 Make sure that you actually have write permissions in the folder you're trying to create the database in.

Comment: If i do this code its work fine, he create db named myDB in distant folder.                               class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('myDB.sqlite');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
    
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

Comment: No idea to my problem ?